# Using VBS to select a value on a dropdownlist in webpage

Tags: html, asp.net, vbscript

I'm currently working on on a script to open a website, select a value in a dropdownlist and do a search, I'm having trouble with the selection of a value in the dropdownlist, below is my vbs code:

```
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "https://website.com/form.aspx"
Do
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop While IE.ReadyState <4 And IE.Busy
'Button to access form
Set SLTOI = IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0_V1_I1_S1_I1_B1")
SLTOI.click
'Dropdownlist element
Set SPCI = IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0_V1_I1_S2_I2_D7")
For Each opt In SPCI.options
    MsgBox opt.value
    If opt.value = "ION CISCO" Then
        opt.Selected = True
    Else
        opt.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```

The source of the dropdownlist is the following (using developers option to inspect the element in IE)

```
<SELECT tabIndex=0 title="" class="v_utCmzxtdUQZu9e3j_0 n_utCmzxtdUQZu9e3j_0 bb_utCmzxtdUQZu9e3j_0 d3_utCmzxtdUQZu9e3j_0" id=ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0_V1_I1_S2_I2_D7 style="DIRECTION: ltr" onfocus="return (DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));" onblur="return (DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" onchange="return (DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));" OriginalId="V1_I1_S2_I2_D7" FormId="ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0" ViewDataNode="12" direction="ltr" wrapped="true" ScriptClass="DropDownList"><OPTION value=""></OPTION><OPTION value="ION CISCO" selected>ION CISCO</OPTION></SELECT>
```

The code executes correctly but the value is not selected in the dropdownlist field (added a Msgbox inside the  For to see if the code executed, but it doesnt enter the For at all), if i select a value manually from the list and then try to select another value, the list only has the value i selected previously, unless i click a clear button the list is not populated again, seems that a script is running to populate the list.

Any ideas on how i can make my code work?, have tried to use the "FireEvent("onchange")" after doing a selection but didnt work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Also, you should declare your IE as an Object rather than a variant

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "https://website.com/form.aspx"
Do
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop While IE.ReadyState <4 And IE.Busy
'Button to access form
Set SLTOI = IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0_V1_I1_S1_I1_B1")
SLTOI.click
'Dropdownlist element
Set SPCI = IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_4e7438b0_6aba_44b0_a0a1_f49486f81665_FormControl0_V1_I1_S2_I2_D7")

Dim SelectThis as String
SelectThis = "ION CISCO"
SPCI.Value = SelectThis
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, from what i know VBS there is no need to dim the variables as something in particular as they are type Variant, never the less gave it a try to set the selected value into a variable and then tried to selected but with no good results :(.

Comment: You are correct. It's usually not required to declare your variables but that doesn't mean it's not good practice to do so. It's easier to start good habits than to break bad ones..